Facing issue: React is null when using JavaScript import maps to import a project into an existing project
I'm developing a project (Project A) to create reusable components using Vite. My goal is to export these components to other existing projects. To achieve this, I'm using JavaScript import maps to import the components from Project A. Project A Repo
I've deployed Project A to Netlify and created a minified bundle. The link to the bundled JavaScript file is:
Bundled minified Project A
Here are the steps I've taken in my Vite configuration for both projects:
Project A (vite.config.js):
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    tsconfigPaths(),
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        postcssImport(),
      ],
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/exports.ts'),
      name: 'components',
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      fileName: (format) => `components.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
    minify: 'terser', 
  },
  define: {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
  },
})


I have excluded react and react dom so that both of them can be used as per the consuming project (that is project B in my case):
and part of package.json looks like
{
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    ....
    "@ant-design/charts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.4.4",
    ....
  }
}

Components are being exported as:
import Chart from "./components/Chart/Chart";
import ButtonComponent from "./components/Button/Button";
export const LPChart = Chart;
export const LPButton = ButtonComponent;


Here are the steps to integrate the exported components using import maps:
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="importmap" defer>
      {
        "imports": {
          "react": "/node_modules/react/index.js",
          "react-dom": "/node_modules/react-dom/index.js",
          "storybook-components": "https://storybook-chart.netlify.app/dist/components.es.js"
        }
      }
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
   ...
  </body>
</html>

Note - I have tried production / development version of react, but it did not work.
"react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" // prod
"react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js" // dev


Project B (vite.config.js):
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import path from 'path';

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tsconfigPaths()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
      "storybook-components":
        "http://localhost:5173/dist/components.es.js"
    },
  },
  define: {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
  },
})


and a part of package.json looks like (Project B)
{
  "name": "importmappoc",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
  ....
}


Problem
When I import the components into project B, two scenarios occur:

If the exported components do not use any React hooks, they are imported and function correctly.
If the exported components use React hooks, an error appears in the console:

The error is as follows:
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (chunk-HZASMJ22.js?v=c5679e87:1067:29)
    at Button (components.es.js:10994:40)
    at Nh (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:3520:11)
    at Vk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6734:15)
    at Uk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6401:15)
    at Tk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6394:9)
    at Ik (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6377:11)
    at Nk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6093:11)
    at Gk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6024:55)
    at J (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:110:21)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (chunk-HZASMJ22.js?v=c5679e87:1067:29)
    at Button (components.es.js:10994:40)
    at Nh (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:3520:11)
    at Vk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6734:15)
    at Uk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6401:15)
    at Tk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6394:9)
    at Ik (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6377:11)
    at Nk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6093:11)
    at Gk (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:6024:55)
    at J (react-dom_client.js?v=1b8ea772:110:21)


The error indicates that React in the exported component is null, and Project B is not utilizing its own React dependency in the above scenario. I have attempted various methods to resolve this issue, but none have been successful.
Can anyone provide assistance to resolve this issue? Please let me know if additional implementation details are needed. I'm really stuck on this and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

It happens because react gets imported twice. Check how you are building/bundling react-dom and its deps. I am pretty sure this is the case if anyone ever runs into a similar issue, react-dom needs to declare react as an external dep as well instead of bundling it into react-dom.
I spent a few hours to finally get around this and realized this was the root cause. Though my setup is a bit different.
